# Problem with content when header is in position fixed: strange margin added

Tags: html, css, position

I'm trying to make a Tesla clone without using flex, but I'm finding problems related to the header: I don't know why hiding the padding relating to the section under the header (this one is on z-index) a big margin appear on top.

Someone can help me?
You can find the code in here and the padding that i would like to hide is on css section, line 152.

[Link]
[`.item__container { height: 100%; padding: 57px 0; }`1]

Thanks for yours help.

Comment: add some code so we can preproduce same problem

Answer (score 0):

There might be different cases:

1. Check whether you are using `ul` it has its own top margin 1em.
2. Check Other Tags The Logo does it contain any similar class like `mt-1,mt-2,mt-3,mt-4,mt-5`.

If above doesn't work share your site link I will fix it.

Comment: Hi, Ajay, thank a lot for you reply, and sorry if i didn't post the link: my mistake.
Link is here: https://codepen.io/emanuelegurini/pen/wvyJYKJ

I just tryed as you suggest, but i didn't fixed it :(

Comment: just use the font-size:"15px; " to set the center UL..

Comment: And as i can the site is not responsive to make it resoponsive just use the "row class and col class to make it responsive"

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WXNeS.png check